# Get-Service on remote machine got 'Cannot find any service with service name' error after change to Prod using Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins

We are using Jenkins to deliver our new windows machine. During deployment, I have a code running on the Jenkins machine to get-service status from a remote server. It works fine in testing environment. However, after it moves to production environment, always complains

> *'Cannot find any service with service name '...''*

But when I log into the machine, the service is there. What's the possible reason it throw this error?

Here is my code:

```
$status = Get-Service -Computer $server  -Name $servicename | %{$_.Status}
```

Before `Get-Service`, I connect to the remote machine using:

```
net use \\$server\c$ $password /USER:$username
```

This step looks fine which means Jenkins can connect to remote server.

Anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: is it possible that the service has not yet started [or finished starting]?

Comment: can you ensure that $server actually contains the server name?

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey that's my original thought, but after I added sleep time, still the same. I also used 'W32Time' to test, it got the same error. But I added test-connection to see if the connection is successful, it returns true.

Comment: Hi @vrdse yes, I also added test-connection for that server using $server and it returns true.

Comment: @milkbone123 - if `Test-Connection` works, then the basic network stuff is running. if WMI or CIM fails, then you seem to have either a WinRM or a DCOM communication problem. have you tried `Test-WSMan`? ///// have you checked the time on the non-responders? windows gets _freaky_ when there are time differences ...

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the user that is used to run the scheduled task is part of the administrator group in the remote server as well